# Manual and for loop return different values even with set.seed

Tags: r

I tried to find the sum of the functions automatically. Then, to make sure it is run as expected I do it manually and using `for` loop, however, the results are different. Here is my code (my function is very harder than this example, but the are similar)

```
mu1 <- list(2,3,4)
sd1 <- list(0.5,0.6,0.7)
w <- c(0.5,0.2,0.3)
set.seed(123)
mylist <- list(rnorm(10,mu1[[1]],sd1[[1]]),
rnorm(10,mu1[[2]],sd[[2]]),
rnorm(10,mu1[[3]],sd[[3]]))
ta <- list(c(0.5,0.6,0.7,0.4,0.3,0.5,0.65,0.2,0.9,0.1),c(0.4,0.6,0.7,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.65,0.2,0.8,0.3),
           c(0.3,0.2,0.7,0.4,0.3,0.5,0.25,0.2,0.6,0.4))
xx <- sum(ta[[1]]*(log(w[1])+dnorm(mylist[[1]],log=T)),ta[[2]]*(log(w[2])+dnorm(mylist[[2]],log = T)),ta[[3]]*
      (log(w[3])+dnorm(mylist[[3]],log = T)))

ll <- list()
for(i in 1:3){
 ll[[i]] <-  ta[[i]]*log(w[i])+dnorm(mylist[[i]],log = T)
 sum(ll[[i]])
}
```

The manual and loop return these result respectively,

```
[1] -89.6547
[1] -84.28907
```

Why these result are unequal. Any help please, is that still due to the `set.seed`.

Comment: I think get the same value as your `for` loop `mapply(function(x, y, z) sum(x*y +dnorm(z, log = TRUE)), ta, log(w), mylist)
#[1] -34.32778 -67.25251 -84.28907`  Also with the manual approach ` `sum(ta[[3]]*log(w[3]) + dnorm(mylist[[3]], log = TRUE))
#[1] -84.28907`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a problem with the braces in the order of execution.  In the first case, due to operator precedence, the `ta[[3]]*log(w[[3]]` happens first and then the output is added to `dnorm(my[[3]], log = TRUE)`.

```
sum(ta[[3]]*log(w[3]) + dnorm(mylist[[3]], log = TRUE))
#[1] -84.28907
```

Whereas, below, we are multiplying the `ta[[3]]` with the sum of (`log(w[3]) + dnrom(mylist[[3]], log = TRUE)`) as it is inside the braces.

```
sum(ta[[3]]*(log(w[3]) + dnorm(mylist[[3]], log = TRUE)))
#[1] -33.48956
```

In the second one, the braces start from the `(log(w[3]...)`

---

Just to check, we are using `mapply` and it gives the output `-89.6547` which is the sum of all the three manual cases.

```
sum(mapply(function(x, y, z) sum(x*(y +dnorm(z, log = TRUE))), ta, log(w), mylist))
#[1] -89.6547
```

Also, if we correct the braces in the `for` loop, the output will be the same

```
ll <- list()
 for(i in 1:3){
  ll[[i]] <-  sum(ta[[i]]*(log(w[i])+dnorm(mylist[[i]],log = T)))

 }
sum(unlist(ll))
#[1] -89.6547
```

Comment: it is amazing. However, I checked my braces and they are good! may I still miss them.

Comment: Yes, I just saw that.

Comment: @Alice I just happened to be online when you posted the question.  I am glad to help you.